# LAN Settings keep reverting back to default - Chrome/IE different settings

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, proxy

My Windows 7 computer seems to not want to allow me to change my LAN settings to add a proxy .pac and save my changes.  I can deselect checkboxes and enter proxy addresses, but after I click "ok", and open the settings again, they revert back to what they were. I was able to find out how to force the option I prefer through the registry keys - though I would rather it just allow me to change my selection through IE tools -> Internet Options.  I had found a work around by changing my group policy settings.  The strange thing here is that it changed my IE settings and my Control Panel -> Internet Options, but when I go to Google Chrome and check the proxy settings, it seems to be going to a different area because the settings aren't the same. (these settings have the title Internet Properties vs IE settings of Internet Options)  I know Chrome is supposed to be using IE's settings, but on my computer they seem to be different.  I was able to force change the Chrome settings to the selection I want, but I can't seem to find where to set the "Use Automatic Configuration Script" url in the registry.  I tried changing the AutoConfigURL in my HKCU registry for Internet Settings in Windows and added one to HKLM with no affect.

I believe a virus caused these problems.  My anti-virus software found it, but it seems not until after it affected my computer.

Can anyone help me to either A) force Chrome to keep a .pac file that I set or B) free the options so I can change them at will without immediately reverting back.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, I spent a few days trying to figure this out and as soon as I post a question, I find the answer.

I found by searching the registry that the key where I was able to adjust the Chrome settings was under HKLM/Software/Wow6432Node/Internet Settings, not directly under HKLM/Software/Microsoft/Windows/Current Version/Internet Settings .  A quick web search, I discovered this was the registry settings for 32 bit programs, which explains why IE and Chrome had different internet settings.  Fortunately, I found Chrome's beta 64-bit download and as soon as I installed, the new Chrome referenced the 64 bit internet settings and everything was fixed!

This doesn't necessarily answer part B of the question, but my computer is back to being fully functional.